# Oracle - Unique constraint over nullable fields

Tags: oracle

I would like to consult / gather some ideas, from you guys, on possible solutions for unique constraint definition over nullable columns in oracle.

Let's have a table of customers

- PK(ID), first_name, last_name are pretty obvious
- EXT_CODE is Unique, visible in application, used to synchronization with 3rd party systems, means, that it's external ID first time delivered by other system, then remains unchanged whole lifetime
- Example: update clients set first_name = 'ABC' where ext_code = 'ABC'

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|ID |FIRST_NAME |LAST_NAME  |EXT_CODE   |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|1  |Peter      |Pletan     |ABC        |
|2  |John       |Dollar     |DEF        |
|3  |Mia        |Zin        |GHI        |
|4  |Jasper     |Blau       |NULL       |
|5  |George     |Khan       |NULL       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Until now, everything is ok, I have EXT_CODE unique per this table, so there is always only one row returned, when update from external system is requested. When there is client with ext_code = null, it cannot be maintained from external system, because where something = null, never returns anything. There can be only one client with same EXT_CODE, but any number of those without this EXT_CODE (column is nullable)

---

Now comes the difficult part.
I decided, that in this table, data for more (independent) customers could be stored. For this reason, I added new column called CUSTOMER_CODE.
This code splits the table virtually into separate spaces, while every customer can see only her data.

For this purpose, oracle vpd (virtual private database) has been introduced.

1. Every customer uses her own oracle user
2. On logon, customer code is loaded
3. Predicate WHERE CUSTOMER_CODE = 'my_code' (loaded in step2) is appended to every query

Modified table might look following

```
+---------------+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|CUSTOMER_CODE  |ID |FIRST_NAME |LAST_NAME  |EXT_CODE   |
+---------------+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|C1             |1  |Peter      |Pletan     |ABC        |
|C1             |2  |John       |Dollar     |DEF        |
|C1             |3  |Mia        |Zin        |GHI        |
|C1             |4  |Jasper     |Blau       |NULL       |
|C1             |5  |George     |Khan       |NULL       |
|C2             |6  |Paul       |Walker     |1          |
|C2             |7  |Simon      |Sleeper    |2          |
|C2             |8  |Lian       |Driver     |3          |
|C2             |9  |Cor        |Pilot      |NULL       |
|C2             |10 |Martin     |Oldman     |NULL       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

That is considered general overview. When customer C1 logs in, she sees only rows 1-5, while C2 6-10.

---

Here come the issues

1. Due to UNIQUE constraint on EXT_CODE, customer C1 and C2 cannot have same ext_code - following two rows already breaks the constraint

```
+---------------+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|CUSTOMER_CODE  |ID |FIRST_NAME |LAST_NAME  |EXT_CODE   |
+---------------+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|C1             |1  |Peter      |Pletan     |ABC        |
|C2             |2  |John       |Dollar     |ABC        |
```

2. That is easily fixable, by instead of UNIQUE(ext_code), i make UNIQUE(CUSTOMER_CODE, EXT_CODE), what causes another issue - I can no more have 2 rows with ext_code empty, because C1, NULL and C1, NULL is the same from oracle's point of view. Example for these rows, ID=4,5. I could have these prior to customer introduction.

**What are my possibilities now ?**
1. Functional based index (drop unique constraint) - index, which would set both values null if any is null, so it doesn't get indexed at all => might be a solution, but indexes are not deferable in opposite to unique constraints

2. Trigger - which checks the data and throw exception (only if both values are not null)
3. Make ext_code not null - place regular unique constraint over combination (ext_code, customer_code) => not viable option
4. Other ideas - I would like to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said which version of Oracle you're using, but from 11g you can use a virtual column with a unique constraint:

```
alter table customer add (unq_col varchar2(24) -- or necessary size
  generated always as (case when ext_code is null then null
    else customer_code||'~'||ext_code end));
alter table customer add (constraint unq_col_con unique (unq_col));
```

The generated column can be built any way you consider safe - with a delimiter if you can identify a character that can never be in one of the columns, or padding, or whatever is suitable.

Then trying to duplicate a code within a customer fails:

```
update customer set ext_code = 'ABC' where ext_code = 'DEF'

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA.UNQ_COL_CON) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
```

But with a different customer is OK:

```
update customer set ext_code = 'ABC' where ext_code = '1';

1 row updated.
```

Comment: This solution seems fine (and I actually have been experimenting with it before). Problem however is, if there are multiple of these kind of constraints on the table. I have to create new virtual column for each of them, don't I ?
In our real database, we have tens of tables with multiple constraints over nullable fields.